# не срабатывает append

Tags: html, jquery

Почему не срабатывает append? input удаляется, но ничего не появляется.
Буду очень признателен.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    var message = $('<span>Ваша заявка принята!</span>');
    $('#panel').append(message);
    $('#button').remove();

  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form" metod="post">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4>ОСТАВЬТЕ ЗАЯВКУ</h4>
    <form id="panel">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя"><br>
      <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Телефон"><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">
    </form>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: посмотри конечную разметку в браузере

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Is it valid to have a html form inside another html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/555928/2881286)

Comment: @AlexanderMashchenko В `form` еще один `form`?

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan не знал, что так нельзя. 
Я убрал внутренний форм и сделал append для .text-center, но от теперь выкидывает мне надпись справа от формы.

Comment: @AlexanderMashchenko док для `html` изучите.

Comment: понял, спасибо вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [спецификации](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element) указано, что среди содержимого формы не может быть других форм.

Так как в твоем случае одна форма вложена в другую, разметка невалидна и браузеры могут обрабатывать ее по своему желанию, например Chrome и EDGE просто удалят внутреннюю форму.

Из-за этого, в момент выполнения скрипта элемента с `id="panel"` нет и соответственно, сообщение добавляется в никуда.

Для решения нужно либо заменить форму на тот же див, если нужна именно такая вложенность, либо убрать внутреннюю форму и вставлять в оставшийся контейнер, например:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    var message = $('<span>Ваша заявка принята!</span>');
    $('#panel').append(message);
    $('#button').remove();

  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form" metod="post">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4>ОСТАВЬТЕ ЗАЯВКУ</h4>
    <div id="panel">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя"><br>
      <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Телефон"><br>
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

---

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    var message = $('<span>Ваша заявка принята!</span>');
    $('#form .text-center').append(message);
    $('#button').remove();

  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form" metod="post">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h4>ОСТАВЬТЕ ЗАЯВКУ</h4>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя"><br>
    <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Телефон"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" value="ОТПРАВИТЬ">
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ох, Спасибо тебе большое.Как раз начал читать твою ссылку. Подскажи, почему ты во втором своем примере сделал так: `$('#form .text-center').append(message);` почему не срабатывает `$(.text-center).append(message);` ?

Comment: @AlexanderMashchenko, `$(.text-center).append(message);` в данном случае синтаксическая ошибка: нет кавычек вокруг селектора. как только их поставишь все будет работать. `$('.text-center').append(message);`. Я добавил `#form` для уточнения, в каком именно элементе надо искать `.text-center` на случай, если элементов с таким классом будет несколько на странице

Comment: Кавычки это я случайно забыл)) Я понял, спасибо еще раз!